# Can Aptana find and replace in multiple files?

Tags: aptana

I have a lot of files that have errors because the imported text uses smart quotes and the export program has replaced these with those crazy symbols. I'd like to just find and replace with Aptana and change all of these in all these files.

It would be useful in a much greater capacity, however, today this is the only thing I need it for. Thanks. Using Aptana 2 if it is different than 3.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> will allow you to search, find, and replace based on workspace, selected files, and projects.

Answer (score 9):

In Mac it's Cmd + Option + G for the curious.

Comment: Too bad your other question collected that many downvotes. Hope that feels a bit better now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Small precision, when search result is shown, a right click on one result gives you "Replace Selected" and "Replace All..."