# Remove br tags from html files

Tags: html, css, windows, file

I need to remove br tags from html files. Currently I have more than 120 html files and each file has more than 30 br tags and I am removing 1 by 1... Is it possible to remove all br tags at once.

Comment: What kind of system are you on?  Linux?  Windows?  Mac?

Comment: I usually use some sort of text editor, then use search and replace. My favorite in windows is `Textpad`. But there might be some gurus here with a nifty command line used together with `cmd.exe`? :)

Comment: You use IDE (like `Aptana`) and import it into IDE and do it at once

Comment: @alireza safian will you please explain a bit more please

Comment: @renusood I'm sorry to replay late. Please, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459640/can-aptana-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files).

Answer (score 5):

Use `br {display:none}` to remove the breakspaces

CSS is more lightweight than jQuery so this is a better solution and faster too.

Answer (score 2):

By using Jquery we can do this,For example

```
$(function(){
  $('body').find('br').remove();
});
```

It may be useful to you